# Database creation failing during django testing

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a functional Django project with a functional database. When I try to run tests on this project, I get this error during database creation:

```
django.db.utils.InternalError: (1553, "Cannot drop index 'One response per question per level': needed in a foreign key constraint")
```

I had a unique_together constraint in one of the tables which I later removed.

This line

```
'One response per question per level'
```

is related to that unique_together constraint and is present in two migration files - first time during the creation of the table and second time during the removal.

When I run the tests, it is throwing this error and the database is not getting created. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did the second migration when you removed the unique together constraint actually work for your local or development and/or production environment?

Comment: @Mehran I don't really remember. It was at least 6  months ago. Is it possible to remove this code from the migration files and make some corresponding changes in the database to reflect these changes?

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea tbh, django migrations are very picky and might need a full database reboot if things get messed up. You can however check if the migration in question got applied or not from the django_migrations table in your database (you'll need to use a db client). Check if the migration in question is inside that table.

Comment: @Mehran Thanks for the tip. Yes, the migration is applied.

Comment: in that case I believe the issue is not database related but on how you're writing your test code, especially when you're trying to ```setUp``` the test case.

Comment: @Mehran I removed the setUp() code and yet it is showing the same error. What more can I share with you to make it easier for you to detect the problem?

Comment: Are the databases you use in your production and local/dev environment different? e.g you use postgres in production but use sqlite in local?

Comment: @Mehran No, I'm using mysql everywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems this is a Django issue https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24757

Comment: @Mehran I see. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a known problem in Mysql [code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24757](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24757#no1)

I'm using this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28560805/5157204) for now.