# Why is pytest throwing an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'" error when testing model creation?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, factory

I'm using Django 2 and trying to write some unit tests for my models.  I have these models ...

```
class CoopTypeManager(models.Manager):

    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get_or_create(name=name)[0]


class CoopType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)

    objects = CoopTypeManager()


class CoopManager(models.Manager):
    # Look up by coop type
    def get_by_type(self, type):
        qset = Coop.objects.filter(type__name=type,
                                   enabled=True)
        return qset

class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType)
    address = AddressField(on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

I have created the following factory for auto-generating these models ...

```
import factory
from .models import CoopType, Coop


class CoopTypeFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    """
        Define Coop Type Factory
    """
    class Meta:
        model = CoopType


class CoopFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    """
        Define Coop Factory
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Coop

    coop_type = factory.SubFactory(CoopTypeFactory)
```

Then I created this simple test ...

```
import pytest
from django.test import TestCase
from .tests.factories import CoopTypeFactory, CoopFactory


class ModelTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        print("setUpTestData: Run once to set up non-modified data for all class methods.")
        pass

    def setUp(self):
        print("setUp: Run once for every test method to setup clean data.")
        pass

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_coop_type_model():
        """ Test coop type model """
        # create coop type model instance
        coop_type = CoopTypeFactory(name="Test Coop Type Name")
        assert coop_type.name == "Test Coop Type Name"
```

but when I run the tests, I get an error, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'"

```
(venv) localhost:web davea$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'test_maps_data'; database exists")
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_maps_data', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 26, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 59, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 601, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 548, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 176, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 76, in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 119, in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 128, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 80, in serialize
    for count, obj in enumerate(queryset, start=1):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 116, in get_objects
    yield from queryset.iterator()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 336, in _iterator
    yield from self._iterable_class(self, chunked_fetch=use_chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1050, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 445, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 50, in pre_sql_setup
    self.setup_query()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 40, in setup_query
    self.query.get_initial_alias()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 886, in get_initial_alias
    alias = self.join(BaseTable(self.get_meta().db_table, None))
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 284, in get_meta
    return self.model._meta
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

**Edit:** Here is a github link if you want to try and reproduce the problem.  Project is in "web" -- https://github.com/chicommons/maps

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but the test ran seamlessly for me, ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHxmz.png)). I think this issue might be specific to your environment.

Comment: Your problem might come from the migrations, are you sure they are up to date?

Comment: @SebCorbin ,when I run "python manage.py makemigrations", I get "No changes detected."  When I run "python manage.py migrate maps", I get "No migrations to apply.".

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, I included the GitHub project link as an edit to my question.  If you have time, I'm interested to see if you're able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Dave try to run your migrations on a fresh database, if you have an error doing that, the problem is narrowed down

Comment: Hi @SebCorbin.  I purged and re-created everything.  Then re-ran the migrations using "python manage.py migrate maps".  Everything ran fine and all tables were re-created successfully.  I'll add instructions to the GitHub link about how to create the database in case you're interested in attempting to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution is, **ignore migrations during the test run**. To do that, create a separate settings module for test environment

```
# /web/maps/test_settings.py
from .settings import *


class DisableMigrations(object):
    # ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28560805/12578202

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return None


MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()
```

Then run test as,

```
python manage.py test --settings=maps.test_settings
```

- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJqLF.png)

**NOTE:** I have made other small changes to the repository to get it done, but I hope those things are not a big deal. (Anyway, I made [a PR here](https://github.com/chicommons/maps/pull/4) for you )

Comment: Hi @ArakkalAbu, would you mind sharing the other small changes you made?  If you want to fork my repo and add your changes there, I can just view them taht way.  I think your solution is working and that the errors I'm getting ("ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.factories'") are easily solved but I'd like to verify.

Comment: Have you not seen my PR?  I have already attached the link in my answer. (I have made some other cleaning, check my commit message... I hope that are self explanatory  ) @Dave

Comment: Oh man I totally missed that (I often ignore my GitHub emails)!  Anyway downloaded your PR and it's working well.  One question -- are there any side effects to ignoring the migrations?  Are there things the factory bot isn't able to do or know without them?

Comment: No problems that I know of. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I had a look at your code on github, and my first warning is: *don't monkeypatch other packages' models, subclass if you can*.

Your usage of django-address is a bit messy, you are using the models and modifying their behavior, but It's quite dangerous.

The incriminating lines are

```
setattr(State._meta, 'default_manager', StateCustomManager())
setattr(Locality._meta, 'default_manager', LocalityCustomManager())
```

These attributes are private (hence the `_` prefixing `_meta` and should not be messed with. I would use `State.add_to_class('objects', StateCustomManager())` instead.

Second warning is: I don't really think your usage of `get_by_natural_key()` and automatically creating objects is quite wise, it may slow your objects accessing.

Comment: Thanks, although I think the reason someone suggested that to me was because it was the only way to get my seed data to load -- "/maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml".  If I try your solution, I'm no longer able to run my seed data command (run using "python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml")

Comment: Did you create the fixture with `manage.py dumpdata`? If so, be sure to put the options `--natural-foreign` and/or `--natural-primary`

Comment: Hi @SebCorbin, No the fixtures file was created using a script (not dumpdata).  Note, I'm not marreid to using pytest or the factories method of running my simple test -- I just figured it was the easiest way to create tests, but I'm open to another way of getting the testing done.

Comment: Then I would suggest https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/ It may not solve your problem though, the fixture should be created with django for full compliance, or if it's about importing data, you can create a command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the Supper class constructor on either of
your derived classes. When you write a derived class, be sure to call
the super class constructor on the child class:

```
class SubClass(SupperClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```